# Simplify my jQuery code, which is growing huge and redundant

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplify

I am no jQuery expert, but I'm learning. I'm using a bit (growing to a LOT) of jQuery to hide some images and show a single image when a thumb is clicked. While this bit of jQuery works, it's horribly inefficient but I am unsure of how to simplify this to something that works on more of a universal level.

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function () {

// Changing the Materials
$("a#shirtred").click(function () {
    $("#selectMaterials img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectShirtRed").addClass("visible");
});

$("a#shirtgrey").click(function () {
    $("#selectMaterials img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectShirtGrey").addClass("visible");
});

$("a#shirtgreen").click(function () {
    $("#selectMaterials img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectShirtGreen").addClass("visible");
});

$("a#shirtblue").click(function () {
    $("#selectMaterials img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectShirtBlue").addClass("visible");
});

// Changing the Collars
$("a#collarred").click(function () {
    $("#selectCollar img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectCollarRed").addClass("visible");
});

$("a#collargrey").click(function () {
    $("#selectCollar img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectCollarGrey").addClass("visible");
});

$("a#collargreen").click(function () {
    $("#selectCollar img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectCollarGreen").addClass("visible");
});

$("a#collarblue").click(function () {
    $("#selectCollar img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectCollarBlue").addClass("visible");
});

// Changing the Cuffs
$("a#cuffred").click(function () {
    $("#selectCuff img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectCuffRed").addClass("visible");
});

$("a#cuffgrey").click(function () {
    $("#selectCuff img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectCuffGrey").addClass("visible");
});

$("a#cuffblue").click(function () {
    $("#selectCuff img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectCuffBlue").addClass("visible");
});

$("a#cuffgreen").click(function () {
    $("#selectCuff img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectCuffGreen").addClass("visible");
});

// Changing the Pockets
$("a#pocketred").click(function () {
    $("#selectPocket img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectPocketRed").addClass("visible");
});

$("a#pocketgrey").click(function () {
    $("#selectPocket img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectPocketGrey").addClass("visible");
});

$("a#pocketblue").click(function () {
    $("#selectPocket img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectPocketBlue").addClass("visible");
});

$("a#pocketgreen").click(function () {
    $("#selectPocket img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img.selectPocketGreen").addClass("visible");
});

});
</scrip>

<!-- Thumbnails which can be clicked on to toggle the larger preview image -->


        <div class="materials">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="shirtgrey"><img src="/grey_shirt.png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="shirtred"><img src="red_shirt.png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="shirtblue"><img src="hblue_shirt.png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="shirtgreen"><img src="green_shirt.png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    </div>


    <div class="collars">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="collargrey"><img  src="grey_collar.png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="collarred"><img  src="red_collar.png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="collarblue"><img  src="blue_collar.png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="collargreen"><img  src="green_collar.png" height="122" width="122" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="cuffs">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="cuffgrey"><img  src="grey_cuff.png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="cuffred"><img  src="red_cuff.png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="cuffblue"><img  src="blue_cuff.png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="cuffgreen"><img  src="/green_cuff.png" height="122" width="122" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="pockets">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="pocketgrey"><img  src="grey_pocket.png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="pocketred"><img  src=".png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="pocketblue"><img  src="blue_pocket.png" height="122" width="122" /></a> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="pocketgreen"><img  src="green_pocket.png" height="122" width="122" /></a>
    </div>

<!-- The larger images where one from each set should be viewable at one time, triggered by the thumb clicked above -->


        <div class="selectionimg"> 
        <div id="selectShirt">
        <img src="grey_shirt.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectShirtGrey show" />        
        <img src="red_shirt.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectShirtRed hide" />        
        <img src="blue_shirt.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectShirtBlue hide" />        
        <img src="green_shirt.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectShirtGreen hide" />  </div>

         <div id="selectCollar">
        <img src="grey_collar.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectCollarGrey show" />        
        <img src="red_collar.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectCollarRed hide" />        
        <img src="blue_collar.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectCollarBlue hide" />        
        <img src="green_collar.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectCollarGreen hide" />       </div>

         <div id="selectCuff">
        <img src="grey_cuff.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectCuffGrey show" />        
        <img src="red_cuff.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectCuffRed hide" />        
        <img src="blue_cuff.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectCuffBlue hide" />        
        <img src="green_cuff.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectCuffGreen hide" />     </div>

         <div id="selectPocket">
        <img src="grey_pocket.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectPocketGrey show" />        
        <img src="hred_pocket.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectPocketRed hide" />        
        <img src="blue_pocket.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectPocketBlue hide" />        
        <img src="green_pocket.png" height="250" width="250" class="selectPocketGreen hide" />   
    </div>     </div>
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$("a[color]").each(function() {        
    $(this).click(function () {
        var color = $(this).attr('color');
        $("#selectCuff img").removeClass("visible");
        $("img[color="+color+"]").addClass("visible");
    });
});
```

like that?

Also you can play with context css classes like that

```
#select img { 
    display:none;
}
#select.red img.red{
    display:inline;
}
```

and add/remove color class on #select div

I've just realize that you don't even need 'each' here

```
$("a[color]").click(function() {                
    var color = $(this).attr('color');
    $("#selectCuff img").removeClass("visible");
    $("img[color="+color+"]").addClass("visible");
});
```

in markup

```
<a href="#" color="grey">show grey</a>
<div id="select">
<img src="grey_collar.png" height="250" width="250" color="grey" />
<img src="red_collar.png" height="250" width="250" color="red" />
</div>
```

Comment: This looks amazing. Can you run me through on how this works? Is this solution assuming I am using the CSS color attribute? If so, I am not. My code posted above may have been misleading with the color ID and class names. This page is more of a mockup that will list potentially over 100 types of materials etc.

Comment: this code suggest you will use custom attribute `color`. Each `img` should have it and each `a`. On `click` of `a` it will takes the value from color attribute of a, hide all `img` and show only `img` that have attribute color with the same value

Comment: I wouldn't get in the habit of storing data in custom attributes.  A better option here would be to use classes.

Comment: You can use `data-` attribute in HTML5 (ref: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Comment: @fudgey: looks reasonable, but class attribute is more convenient when using with jquery

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this? (check for corrct case etc..not tested)

```
<script> 

function setupMaterialsClick(name)
{
   $("a#" + name).click(function () { 
       $("#selectMaterials img").removeClass("visible"); 
       $("img.select" + name).addClass("visible"); 
   }); 
}

$(document).ready(function () 
{ 

   // Changing the Materials 
   setupMaterialsClick("shirtred");
   // etc

   // Other bits

}); 

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your classes to match the case of the ids of the links, then do something like:

```
$('materials a').bind(changeSelection);
$('collars a').bind(changeSelection);
$('cuffs a').bind(changeSelection);
$('pockets a').bind(changeSelection);

function changeSelection()
{
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 var selectClass = 'img.select'+id;
 $("#selectPocket img").removeClass("visible"); 
 $(selectClass).addClass("visible"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    var src = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
    var img = $(".selectionimg").find("img[src$='"+src+"']");
    img.addClass("visible").siblings().removeClass("visible");
    return false;
  });
});
```

This assumes, that the selected images are the same src as the corresponding clickable images.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test this with images, but you can shorten your HTML and script as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 /* names in the materials variable must match the image file name */
 /* the script will form the filename as follows: grey_shirt.png */
 var materials = {
  'shirt'  : ["grey", "red", "blue", "green"],
  'collar' : ["grey", "red", "blue", "green"],
  'cuff'   : ["grey", "red", "blue", "green"],
  'pocket' : ["grey", "red", "blue", "green"]
 }
 /* Set up Content */
 var i, c = '', s = '<div class="selectionimg">';
 $.each(materials, function(key, value){
  c += '<div class="' + key + '">';
  s += '<div class="select' + key + '">';
  for (i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
   c += '<a href="#" rel="' + value[i] + '"><img class="thumb" src="' + value[i] + '_' + key + '.png"></a>';
   s += '<img src="' + value[i] + '_' + key + '.png" height="250" width="250" class="large-img select' + value[i];
   s += (i==0) ? ' show" />' : ' hide" />'; // add show class only the first selection
  }
  c += '</div>';
  s += '</div>';
 })
 $('#content').html(c + s + '</div>');

 /* Set up scripting */
 $('#content a').click(function(){
  var type = $(this).parent().attr('class');
  var color = $(this).attr('rel');
  $('.select' + type).find('img').removeClass('visible').end()
   .find('img.select' + color).addClass('visible');
  return false;
 })
})
```